# Telnetlib IAC code not working how they should

Tags: python, networking, automation, telnetlib

I was trying to make an auto break function for network automation with telnetlib,
but when i started digging i found out about IAC codes and tried using them but when i type for example `tn.write(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.DO + telnetlib.TM)` device itself return some char in this case `b'\x08 \x08}\x07'` and I'm not sure how to use IAC codes with telnetlib.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever will have this issue, just go to telnetlib main file and comment this line

```
buffer.replace(IAC, IAC+IAC)
```